# Can two spring boot apps use same scheduler tables(Quartz)?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a new Spring boot App

-App Custom1 
-App Custom2

They both share same Database instance. 
Custom 1 is already using scheduler tables.

Can Custom 2 use same set of QRTZ tables used by Custom 1?

Will it affect and block each others jobs?

Comment: They will form a cluster if you make them use the same QRTZ tables. Refer to http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html for more details

Comment: I think i can create a microservice of scheduler and can have jobs of both my apps in that , by that i will have one scheduler instance for both the apps.